# changing order of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was tasked with changing the order then drawing and calculating the integral $\int _0^2 dy\:\int _{y}^{y+2}\:\frac{x}{y+2}dx$...which got very complex. I understood that the D area had to be split in two so for $I_1$ we have $I_1 = \int _0^2 dx\:\int _{0}^{x}\:\frac{x}{y+2}dy$ which later turns to become $ \int _{0}^{2}\:x(lan(x+2) - lan(2))dx$ but this is a rather complicated calculation...so how do we do it?

Answer (score 1):

it is much easier **not** to change the order of integration

$$I = \int_0^2 \int _y^{y+2} \frac{x}{y+2} dx dy = \frac 12 \int_0^2 \frac {(y+2)^2-y^2}{y+2} dy = \frac 12 \int_0^2 \frac {4y+4}{y+2} dy$$

$$= \frac 12 \int_0^2 \left( 4 - \frac {4}{y+2} \right )dy $$

which is not too difficult to calculate.

if you must change the order, you would need to calculate

$$ I = \int_0^2 \int _0^x \frac{x}{y+2} dy dx + \int_2^4 \int _{x-2}^2 \frac{x}{y+2} dy dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your $D$ is the parallelogram of vertices $(0,0), (2,0), (4,2), (2,2)$. When changing the order of integration you will split $D$ into two triangles with a common edge (the line segment joining $(2,0)$ and $(2,2)$). The integral will split accordingly into two integrals: $\int \limits _0 ^2 \mathbb d x \int \limits _0 ^x \mathbb dy + \int \limits _2 ^4 \mathbb d x \int \limits _{x-2} ^2 \mathbb d y$. You then compute itegrals of the form $\int x \log(x+a) \mathbb d x$ by parts, integrating $x$ and deriving $\log$ (this is standard procedure).